# How to convert string to URL with arq/tarql?

Tags: sparql, arq

I got a TSV file that I'm converting with `tarql`.

Column `prop` has strings like `dc:source`, `skos:broader` etc. How can I convert these to the corresponding URLs? Assume I have all needed prefixes defined in the `tarql` query.

I can do this statically eg `uri(concat(str(dc:),"source"))` but how to do it dynamically? The problem can be narrowed to this: given a prefix `dc:` how to expand it to the appropriate URL?

Looked at [ARQ functions](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-function.html) but didn't find anything appropriate. If there's no other solution, I can use a VALUES table that repeats the prefixes and namespaces, but what an ugly solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tarql:expandPrefixedName(?qname)` function (*completely coincidentally* committed [just today](https://github.com/tarql/tarql/commit/249e6d35d90eb09ceaef33bd46f194db7e8c6024)) does exactly what you need: It expands a prefixed name to a full IRI, using any prefixes declared in the query.

The `tarql` namespace is declared implicitly in every Tarql query.