# How to determine or filter datatype of a rdflib literal?

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I haven't used rdflib in a while and am writing some trivial code based on https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_graphs.html#basic-triple-matching

like

```py
from rdflib import Graph

graph = Graph()
ttl_input = "dir/file.ttl"
graph.parse(ttl_input, format='ttl')

for s, p, o in graph.triples((None, None, None)):
    print(f"{s} {p} {o} {o}")
```

I would like to limit the returned `graph.triples` to ones where the object `o` has datatype xsd:anyURI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```py
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.namespace import NamespaceManager, XSD

graph = Graph()
ttl_input = "dir/file.ttl"
graph.parse(ttl_input, format='ttl')

for s, p, o in graph:
    if o.__class__ == rdflib.term.Literal and o.datatype == XSD.anyURI:
        print(f"{s} {p} {o}")
```

As for your previous question, replace the last line with this one:

```py
        print(f"{s} {p} {graph.namespace_manager.expand_curie(o.value)}")
```

Comment: Good to hear from you again. Yes, that last line does answer  [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962922/convert-anyuri-typed-string-representations-of-curies-to-real-curies-or-iris#autocomment135679097)

Comment: Some of my XSD.anyURI literals are in the form "UUID:...UUID characters...". Your `expand_curie` solution requires that I define an expansion for UUID, so I end up with IRIs like `<http://www.example.org/UUID#...UUID characters...>`. Ideally I would get `urn:uuid:...UUID characters...` IRIs. Can you suggest special handling for that? I could start a new question.

Comment: `URIRef(f"urn:uuid:{obj_cuire_string_parts[1]}")`